# How Can I Output Enterprise Features List To CSV?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, feature-activation

I am trying to output to a CSV file the list of activate enterprise features in our sites with DisplayName, GUID and Scope as the content that is written to the CSV file.

I have the following Powershell script but it does not output the DisplayName or the Scope or the GUID - it will only output the url and title of the site that the feature is activated on:

```
$sites = Get-SPSite -Limit All -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach ($site in $sites)
{
    $webs = Get-SPWeb -site $site.Url -Limit ALL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach ($web in $webs) 
{       

    $premiumfeatures = Get-SPFeature "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features" -Web $web.Url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select DisplayName, Scope, ID | Sort -Property Scope,DisplayName | FT -GroupBy Scope DisplayName,Id

    foreach ($premiumfeature in $premiumfeatures) 
    {            
        $featureEnabled = "Feature Enabled On: " + $web.Url + " " + $web.Title + " " + $premiumfeature.DisplayName
        Write-Host $featureEnabled
        Add-Content c:\activated_enterprise_features.csv $featureEnabled
    }
    $web.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()
}
```

How can I output the DisplayName, Scope and ID for a feature to CSV?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this command simply

```
Get-SPFeature -Site "siteurl" | Sort DisplayName | FT DisplayName,scope,Id  > Desktop\feature.csv
```

FYI:- [Powershell command to find active features for site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76245/powershell-command-to-find-active-features-for-site-collection)

Comment: does this give me a list of enterprise features?

Comment: Yes, actually enterprise edition will include all SharePoint feature--Foundation + Standard + (features added in enterprise)

Comment: I am not looking for all features - only Enterprise - hence my script.  I am trying to find only the enterprise features that are activated.  How do I do that?

Comment: But SharePoint Enterprise edition include all features as I said. Enterprise is top version of SharePoint, hence include all features. So how are differentiating enterprise features and other features as they are part of enterprise itself.

Comment: Enterprise + Activated is different than "all enterprise features". I want to know which enterprise features are activated in my farm.  This is for licensing purposes.

Comment: It list those feature which are active on site only, isn't?